# Get the dynamic value of name of the submit input in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, request, twig, submit

i have a search field and submit button. What i want to do is when the button is clicked, the value of the name of the search field is send to the controller. The problem is the name is dynamic like this name="select-{{ variable }}".
Without the {{ variable }}, i can easily get it but as it varies i don't know how to get it. Please give a clue. The code :

```
            <form class="form-inline" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="select-{{ variable }}" placeholder="Search" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-success" id="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
<input type="text" name="select[1]" />
<input type="text" name="select[2]" />
<input type="text" name="select[3]" />
```

Php

```
foreach($_POST['select'] as $key => $value) {
    echo "text $key = $value";
}
```

If you mean you want to get their values in PHP easily, just name them like "name[]".

```
<input type="text" name="input[]" />
```

php

```
foreach($_POST['input'] as $value) {
  // do what you want with the $value
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

> i have never been satisfied by this website. Every time i ask
>   question, people ignore me

It's less than one hour ago you asked the question, have some patience..

It is a bit unclear what you want to achieve, maybe there are easier ways of getting the job done. But I have tried to solve your problem:

**Alternative 1**

Perhaps you can set the input name just before submitting the form? Using AngularJS you can do this in a function specified with ng-click="".

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>

    <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    
        <form class="form-inline" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="form_name" placegolder="form-name" ng-model="variable"/>
                <input type="text" name="{{name_variable}}" placeholder="My Name is: {{name_variable}}" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
            </div>
    
            <script>
                var app = angular.module('app', []);
    
                app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
                    $scope.variable = '';
    
                    // Submit function
                    $scope.submit = function() {
                        $scope.name_variable = 'select-' + $scope.variable;
                        alert('Input Name: ' + $scope.name_variable);
                    }
                });
            </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Alternative 2**

If you need to have the form name dynamically updated as soon as "variable" changes, then you can use $watch method to assign a new value to "name_variable" each time "variable" changes:

```html
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

    <form class="form-inline" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="form_name" placegolder="form-name" ng-model="variable"/>
            <input type="text" name="{{name_variable}}" placeholder="My name is: {{name_variable}}" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
        </div>

        <script>
            var app = angular.module('app', []);

            app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.variable = '';
                
                // Watch the var "variable" for change and update "name_variable"
                $scope.$watch('variable',
                        function(newValue, oldValue) {
                            $scope.name_variable = 'select-' + newValue;
                        });

                // Submit function
                $scope.submit = function() {
                    alert('Input Name: ' + $scope.name_variable);
                }
            });
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're so far of what i want to do so any way it doesn't matter i finally found the solution. Thank so much any way.